# Maintain the span from HTTP calls using feign clients with micrometer

Tags: java, spring, http, micrometer, micrometer-tracing

using spring boot 3.1.5 I migrated my code from sleuth to micrometer for tracing. I have it working loggin traceId and spanId but as somebody already asked here [Should Micrometer generate a new Span each time a Spring Boot Server receives a request and each time Resttemplate is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044612/should-micrometer-generate-a-new-span-each-time-a-spring-boot-server-receives-a), I am trying to maintain the spanId when I call to other microservices through http. I am using spring cloud open feign.

I have the next feign configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfiguration {

    
    @Bean
    public Capability capability(final MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new MicrometerCapability(registry);
    }    
    
    @Bean
    public Logger.Level loggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    
    }
}
```

1. Why the old sleuth by default not created a new span in rest calls and why micrometer does it?. To me it doesnt make any sense to create new span.
2. How to maintain the span from HTTP calls using feign clients?

Thanks!!